# #10 #13 at the end of console line ! in SH

Tags: console, sh, settings, freepascal

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkS51.png)

Hello People!,

I am trying to start AVRDUDE from a .sh script.
Only the #13 is missing at the end of eatch line.

Does anybody know what command to put in my .sh script, so the lines appear with #10#13 at the end?

PS: It is to execute a FPC console program where AVRDUDE has to run in de commandline parameters, line by line. So maybe a SH script in between. To solve it.

Greets, Wouter van Wegen

Comment: Just set your terminal program to use linux line endings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.